# Configure Moxy Configuration without Compile-Time dependency

Tags: jaxb2, moxy

I am moving my project code to Glassfish 4.0 post-JavaONE and realized I have a maven compile and bundle dependency on eclipelink and moxy. (both of which should be provided now in GS4).  As well, since Moxy is now the default JAXB provider for JSON serialization I want to remove this compile/provided dependency.  However I need to configure the provider to not output "@" for the attribute prefix.

Short of doing a reflective lookup of the provider, is there another way to do this other than have a compile time dependency?

Before I was doing the following...

```
MOXyJsonProvider moxyJsonProvider = new MOXyJsonProvider();
moxyJsonProvider.setAttributePrefix("");
```

In my application.

Comment: I should also add I tried also to instead of configuring the provider in this manner, I tried using the ContextResolver pattern as described here: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxy-is-new-default-json-binding.html but this did not result in the correct output (the ids were still output as @id), even though I did verify the provider was called/registered by the Application (but printing out the known providers during server startup)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following using Jersey dependencies instead of MOXy ones.

```java
import javax.ws.rs.ext.*;
import org.glassfish.jersey.moxy.json.MoxyJsonConfig;

@Provider
public class MOXyJsonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<MoxyJsonConfig> {

    private final MoxyJsonConfig config;

    public MOXyJsonContextResolver() {
        config = new MoxyJsonConfig()
            .setAttributePrefix("");
    }

    @Override
    public MoxyJsonConfig getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return config;
    }

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxy-is-new-default-json-binding.html

---

**UPDATE**

I noticed in the comments section on your question you mentioned you tried this approach without success.  Can you post what you tried?

Comment: Ok, I added your class verbatim (which was pretty much what I had) and I modified my Application class commenting out the getSingletons() method that was previously configuring the MOXyJsonProvider.  Instead I modified the constructor to include the package that has the ContextResolver.  I also added a console.log for the constructor and getContext() to ensure it is picked up.  I see the ContextResolver is picked up as a Provider class during server startup, but it is **not** calling the getContext() method (the context to set the attributePrefix to "" it is never requested)